# Target iframe with links using jquery not working

Tags: jquery, iframe, hyperlink, target

Why does this not work? I know I can use target but I need to do with jquery.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="test1.html" onclick="test()">Test 1</a> <br>
        <a href="test2.html" onclick="test()">Test 2</a>
        <p><iframe id="viewer" src="" frameborder="1" style="width:400px; height:600px"></iframe>
        <script>
            function test() {
                var goto = $('this').attr('href');
                $('#viewer').attr('src', goto);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the console say? Have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your code is that `$('this')` is looking for HTML Element which doesn't exits.

For immediate problem, pass the element using `test(this)`

```
<a href="test1.html" onclick="test(this)">Test 1</a>
```

*Script*

```
function test(elem) {
    $('#viewer').attr('src', elem.href);
}
```

As you are using jquery bind event using it

```
//Document ready handler which executes when DOM is complety loaded
$(function(){

    //Bind event
    $('a').on('click', function(e){

        //Cancel default action
        e.preventDefault();

        //Here this refers to element which invoked the event handler
        var goto = $(this).attr('href'); //this.href can also be used

        $('#viewer').attr('src', goto);
    }); 
});
```

*HTML*

```
<a href="test1.html">Test 1</a>
<a href="test2.html">Test 2</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve this you need to make few changes.

Markup

```
<a href="test1.html">Test 1</a>
<a href="test2.html">Test 2</a>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(a).click(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         var goto = $('this').attr('href');
         $('#viewer').attr('src', goto);
    });
});
```

The problem is that when you click on the anchor, the href of the current window is changed to respective href specified in href attribute of anchor tag. So you need to prevent the default handling. Hence, added **event.preventDefault()** in function to achieve so.